# androidでEditText長押しで予測変換機能のあるAutoCompleteTextView付きのダイアログを表示させたいがエラーになる

Tags: java, android

onCreate内でEditTextが長押しされた際に予測変換機能EditText付きのダイアログを作成したいのですがエラーが出てしまいます。

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

ダイアログ内dialog_edittextでなくmainのAutoCompleteTextViewでは問題なく動きますので、恐らくR.id.dialog_edittextがうまく取得出来てないのだと思います。誰かわかる方教えて下さい。

---

```
 EditText editNaiyo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.n_naiyo);


        //ボタンがロングタッチされたときの処理
        editNaiyo.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                final View inputView = factory.inflate(R.layout.input_dailog, null);

                // ダイアログの作成(AlertDialog.Builder)
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("テスト")
                        .setView(inputView)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int whichButton) {
                                // キャンセル処理 
                                    }
                                }).create().show();

                //EditText edit = (EditText) inputView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
                 helper = new DBOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);// DB作成
                SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                AutoCompleteTextView inputTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
                Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{"rowid as _id", "TOKNA"}, null,null , null, null, null);
                CursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        cursor,
                        new String[]{"kco"},
                        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                        0);

               // adapter.getCursorToStringConverter(new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
                //   @Override
                 //  public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
                  //     return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kname"));
                  //  }
                 //});
                inputTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
                return false;
            }


        });
```

input_dailog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"     android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:text="テスト"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_edittext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"     android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。以下のような記述に変更するとうまく動きました。

```
AutoCompleteTextView inputTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) inputView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
```